# LLVM: passing alloca as a function argument

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I want an LLVM IR code equivalent to

```
double x = 4.93;
printf("hello world: %f", x);
```

In my LLVM IR code, I got from [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ad7ro8) and after neating the code, it will become something like

```
%x = alloca double, align 8
store double 4.930000e+00, double* %x, align 8
%1 = load double, double* %x, align 8
%2 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([20 x i8], [20 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), double %1)
```

No error. No problem so far.

---

But to me, `%1` look redundant. However, it looks like I cannot remove this medium. The following code

```
%x = alloca double, align 8
store double 4.930000e+00, double* %x, align 8
%2 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([20 x i8], [20 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), double %x)
```

leads to error

```
llvm-as-9: test.ll:26:113: error: '%x' defined with type 'double*' but expected 'double'
%2 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([20 x i8], [20 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0), double %x)
                                                                                                                ^
```

Now I am wondering if what I'm doing to remove `%1` is really possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alloca` instruction returns a pointer, so in your code `%x` is of `double*` type. You have to `load` from a `double*` to get a `double`.

In your case it should be possible to create a `double` constant with `4.930000e+00` value and use this value as `printf` argument directly.

The same effect can be achieved by running optimization passes on your first snippet.